Quadratic modular equations
Is there a general way to solve a modular equation in this form?
$$ax^2 + bx + c \equiv 0 \pmod n$$
Maybe I should first write the LHS as a square. So I have:
$$\left(x\sqrt a + \frac b{2\sqrt a}\right)^2 \equiv \frac{b^2}{4a} - c \pmod n$$
But I don't know how to continue now. Also, the RHS might not be integer.
So is there a general way to proceed?

This problem comprises a full chapter of a number theory course.

You can use the quadratic equation, at least if $n$ is odd.  Still have to extract a square root though.

We should be careful: $a$ might not have a square root modulo $n$. But if it is relatively prime to $n$, you can multiply both sides by $a^{-1}$ to reduce to the monic case $x^2+a^{-1}bx+a^{-1}c\equiv0$ (mod $n$). (And it's always worth considering using the Chinese remainder theorem to split the congruence modulo $n$ into congruences modulo its prime power factors, which makes the non-relatively-prime case much easier as well, as well as the existence of square roots.)

See here in the linked dupe for how to generalize the quadratic formula to $,\Bbb Z_n = \Bbb Z\bmod n.\ \ $
